# Fade in-out with CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find a way to make a text fade in on load and fade out after a few seconds using CSS. I have searched around S.O and Google but I can't find something like that. Basically the text fades in on load, then fades out instantly all within some seconds. So for example, I could have a 2s fade-in and a 4s fade out.

Here's what I used for fade-in:

```
.text { 
     -webkit-animation: fadein 4s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 4s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 4s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 4s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 4s;
}

 @keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Now I'm trying to have the same text have a fade out happen instantly after the fade in. Is that even possible with CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add a percentage in your `@keyframes`:

```
.text {
    /* fade in */
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s;
    /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
    -moz-animation: fadeinout 4s;
    /* Firefox < 16 */
    -ms-animation: fadeinout 4s;
    /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-animation: fadeinout 4s;
    /* Opera < 12.1 */
    animation: fadeinout 4s;
}
@keyframes fadeinout {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    33% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Although to do exactly what you are asking, initially set `opacity: 0;`, like this, and adjust to `6s`:

```css
        .text {
          opacity: 0;
          /* fade in */
          -webkit-animation: fadeinout 6s;
          /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
          -moz-animation: fadeinout 6s;
          /* Firefox < 16 */
          -ms-animation: fadeinout 6s;
          /* Internet Explorer */
          -o-animation: fadeinout 6s;
          /* Opera < 12.1 */
          animation: fadeinout 6s;
        }

        @keyframes fadeinout {
          from {
            opacity: 0;
          }
          33% {
            opacity: 1;
          }

          to {
            opacity: 0;
          }
        }
```

```html
<p class="text">faded</p>
```

That way the text will stay hidden after fading out.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/hhaLn42o/

Answer (score 0):

You can use percentage denotion, and keep default opacity to 0.

```
label{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 4s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 4s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 4s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 4s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 4s;
}

 @keyframes fadein {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    50%   { opacity: 1; }
     100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Fiddle Demo-http://jsfiddle.net/cp8yjdcj/

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. Your keyframe should be something like this.

```
 @keyframes fadein {
   0% { opacity: 0; }
   50%   { opacity: 1; }
   100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

To stay faded out. You need to add `opacity: 0;` to your `.text` class. Here's a fiddle demo for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/Lk895rsa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better approach is to create two animations and apply them to the same element with the second animation being delayed over the time it takes for the first animation to run.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r5huo3zn/.

CSS:

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}

.fadeInOut {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 2s linear, fadeOut 4s linear 2s forwards;
}
```

It is also possible to just use one animation; however, if you want a two second fade in and 4 second fade out, then your animation breakpoints should be 0%, 33%, and 100% over a 6 second run time.

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9vqccjg1/.

CSS:

```
@keyframes fadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;   
    }

    33% {
        opacity: 1;    
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.fadeInOut {
    animation: fadeInOut 6s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```